# tomcat not reading environment variables

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a tomcat application running on AKS. I created bunch of environment variables so when tomcat launches, it can replace the value. When I use `printenv` in the container, it shows all the environment variables set via deployment.yaml.

However, when tomcat starts, it still doesn't recognizes environment variable, and says something like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PACSDemoController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${widgetsRestBaseUrl}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class BaseDemoController {  
    protected URI restUri;

    @Resource(name = "widgetsRestBaseUrl")
    protected String widgetsRestBaseUrl;

    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerUploaderUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerUploaderUrl;

    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerViewerUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerViewerUrl;

    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerStudySelectionUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerStudySelectionUrl;
    
    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerHieStudySelectionUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerHieStudySelectionUrl;

    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerPatientHistoryUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerPatientHistoryUrl;
    
    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerShareImageUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerShareImageUrl;

    @Resource(name = "widgetServerPacsConfigUrl")
    protected String widgetServerPacsConfigUrl;
    @Resource(name = "apiNominate")
    protected String apiNominate;

    @Resource(name = "apiPacsConfig")
    protected String apiPacsConfig;
    @Resource(name = "widgetsServerNominatePacsUrl")
    protected String widgetsServerNominatePacsUrl;
    

    @Resource(name = "apiBaseUrl")
    protected String apiBaseUrl;    

    @Resource(name = "widgetsBasicPacsConfigUrl")
    protected String widgetsBasicPacsConfigUrl;
    
    @Resource(name = "auth0Domain")
    protected String auth0Domain;    
    
    @Resource(name = "widgetAuth0Audience")
    protected String widgetAuth0Audience;    
    
    @Resource(name = "apiAuth0Audience")
    protected String apiAuth0Audience;    
   
    @Autowired
    protected EpicTokenService epicTokenService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws URISyntaxException {
        restUri = new URI(widgetsRestBaseUrl);
    }
```

All of these resources are coming from `jndi.xml`:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <bean id="apiBaseUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${apiBaseUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsRestBaseUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsRestBaseUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerUploaderUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerUploaderUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerViewerUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerViewerUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerStudySelectionUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerStudySelectionUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerPatientHistoryUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerPatientHistoryUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerShareImageUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerShareImageUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetServerPacsConfigUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetServerPacsConfigUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="apiPacsConfig" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${apiPacsConfig}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="apiNominate" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${apiNominate}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerNominatePacsUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerNominatePacsUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsBasicPacsConfigUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsBasicPacsConfigUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetsServerHieStudySelectionUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsServerHieStudySelectionUrl}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="apiAuth0Audience" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${apiAuth0Audience}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="widgetAuth0Audience" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetAuth0Audience}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="auth0Domain" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${auth0Domain}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am not sure why this is not working. I have two project almost exactly same, and one project works without a problem. Any suggestion?

Update: PACDemoController extends from BaseDemoController:

```
@Controller
public class PACSDemoController extends BaseDemoController {
```

and error is coming from @PostConstruct in BaseDemoController. Here is the log:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${widgetsRestBaseUrl}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at com.accelarad.smr.widgets.demo.BaseDemoController.initialize(BaseDemoController.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: The error message says..  `Error creating bean with name 'PACSDemoController'`   Please include the code for the `PACSDemoController` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't have anything to do with the replacement of `${...}` with the value of the corresponding system environment variable. It only replaces those values in its own configuration files (`server.xml`, various `context.xml` descriptors, etc.).

If you want Spring to replace those property placeholders `${...}`, you need to add a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to your application context. This can be done through:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder />
    ...
</beans>
```

However it is much easier to inject the property values directly from the Spring [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) using the [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation instead of creating hundreds of beans of type `java.lang.String`.

Comment: You are right that tomcat is not responsible for replacement. However, I do have this in my pom.xml. I also have `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` class coming from spring.
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Thanks! I missed `<context:property-placeholder />` part. I added it to context.xml and it works. I am pretty sure it will work if I add it to jndi.xml as well.

Comment: You didn't explain what `jndi.xml` and `context.xml` are (these are note default Spring names), but I assume that `context.xml` imports `jndi.xml` so it should work.